# Linux redirection question

Tags: linux, command-line, unix, shell, redirection

What does the following do on Linux?

> cat <> FIFO |

Where FIFO is a FIFO created in the current directory.

Answer (score 3):

in `bash` the redirection operator `<>` causes a file to be opened for both reading and writing (on file descriptor 0 by default, although you can specify another).

see the [bash manual page on redirections](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Redirections), section 3.6.10

Answer (score 0):

You can't both read and write onto the same pipe.

Comment: I think the final pipe is a typo. Someone should edit.